# PHP - I have like 971 checkboxes in my form, and i am trying to send the checkbox data as post method, but i'm only getting like 952 one's

Tags: php, forms, post

I have like 971 checkboxes in my form, and i am trying to send the checkbox data as post method, but i'm only getting like 952 one's

- At first no data was being submitted, then i tried by editing php.ini
  file and giving **max_input_vars = 2000**
- That resulted in passing the form data but only 951 checkboxes were
  passed, rest are not obtained in  $_POST.

Anyone one know of solving this or a better alternative for passing the checklist data?

```
<!--{if array_key_exists($host, $active)}-->                                                               
<input type="hidden" name="check_list[<!--{$host}-->]" value="0"/>
                                                            
<input class="sub_servers" id="server_check" type="checkbox" 
                                                                   
       value="1" name="check_list[<!--{$host}-->]" checked/>
                                                        
<!--{else}-->                                                            
<input type="hidden" name="check_list[<!--{$host}-->]" value="0"/>
                                                            
<input class="sub_servers" id="server_check" type="checkbox" 
                                                                   
       value="1" name="check_list[<!--{$host}-->]"/>
<!--{/if}-->
```

The idea was to insert to database table the checkboxes checked & those unchecked.
That is why the whole checklist data irrespective of checked or not, at first is being saved to db. Then if a checkbox from the list gots unchecked and sumbitted, can check for that entry in table and update its status.

Any one has any better idea ? As the form is not allowing me to send all the checkbox data to php.

Comment: Are there other fields on the form? How many other fields

Comment: You'll only see the checkboxes that are actually checked. Unchecked check boxes aren't included in the POST data.

Comment: Slightly O/T, but that sounds like a terrible form to have to use. Is there no way to easily split it down into more manageable sections?

Comment: @RiggsFolly There is also hidden fields. See the code, it runs in a loop.

Comment: @droopsnoot This is a drop down like section containing checklists which are populated from database tables.

Comment: Ok regarding the hidden field, `971*2=1,942` so assuming you have at least a few other fields, did you try `max_input_vars = 3000`

Comment: _Small point_ All 971 checkboxes appear to be using the same `id="server_check"` The `id` attribute should be unique on a page. So either make it unique or if you are not actually using any JS to manipulate these elements, leave it out. You only need the `name` attribute to get the data to PHP

Comment: Actually it was the duplicate checklist values that were getting removed. I don't know why but the duplicate ones were not posting to PHP. I have adjusted the max_input_vars to 3000 and now the checklist values are being available in post.

Comment: But the way i used to check and uncheck the checkboxes and save it to table is worse. Couldnot think of a much better way!